# Perform "bigger than" on more than two digits

Tags: bash, variables, numerical-methods

I've tried to google this but I'm not sure how I should form my search correctly. I'm new at programming and I've managed with the help of this community and google, create an OP5 check that's written in bash.

The OP5 checks calls an expect script that logs on to a device using SSH and performs a set of commands and writes the output to a file. The file will contains the following text:

"Count: 46"

In the OP5 check I grep out the numerical value and then form a "bigger than" statement that compares the variable from the expect script and the -c (critical) -w (warning limit) variables that's set when the script runs.

Now here's my dilemma. It seems that the "bigger than" statement only reads the two digits. When I set a warning limit at 1500 and a critical limit at 1700. It reads it as "15" and "17" thus causing a critical warning in the surveillance program.

Currently the variable that I create using grep looks like this:

```
VPNCount=$(grep -o '[0-9]\+' $ExpectFolder/$HOSTADDRESS.op5.vpn.results)
```

Is there something I can do to make the script understand that 1500 and 1700 is a bigger value than 46 and so that it reads at least 5 digits?

Comment: [OP5](http://www.op5.com/) is apparently a service monitoring framework. I had never heard about it.

Comment: can you show your comparison statement?

Comment: This is not how Bash works, and is probably a configuration error or bug in your OP5 installation. I suggest you bring it up with their support.

Comment: If you can come up with a stand-alone Bash snippet which exhibits this behavior, post that here (probably instead of most of your current question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the comparison statement used, it is not easy to figure what could have gone wrong but here is a stab in the dark:

Notice that if the comparison is string-based, "46" is larger than "1500"

```
if [[ 46 > 1500 ]]; then echo true; fi
> true
```

On the other hand if you do a integer comparison, you will get the correct result:

```
if [ 46 -gt 1500 ]; then echo true; fi
>
```

Could this have been the issue?

More info [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

Comment: Hey everyone. OK so here's the comparison: VPNCount=$(grep -o '[0-9]\+' $ExpectFolder/$HOSTADDRESS.op5.vpn.results)
if [[ "$VPNCount" > $CRITICAL ]] then
echo "The amount of VPN tunnels exceeds the critical threshold - (Configured Tunnels:$VPNCount)"
# Exit with status Critical (exit code 2)   exit 2 - So I think that you're correct. I'm going to try your method. :)